# Django not showing images in editor (404 error)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, summernote

I'm try create post and add to this post images. And i'm use for this Django-summernote in Django 3.0.
Picture upload to folder on hard disk, but not showing in editor. Console show 404 Error.
Please, give me advice how to fix it?
Thank you!

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'  # Show summernote with Bootstrap4

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/api/article/%i/" % self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPFZM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First add forward slash in  `MEDIA_ROOT`:
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`

Then Check following stuffs:

1. `DEBUG = True` in your settings
2. Inspect Post model table in your database whether image field have any value(did you run makemigrations & migrate commands?)
3. Take a look at INSTALLED_APPS setting
4. if it is a uploaded file nor a static file so in your template write:

`<img src="{{post_object.image.url}}" />`

and add post_object in view context

Comment: Hello! Thank you for yor help. 
DEBUG = True in settings help with this situation. 
But this is will help for local using. But how I'm can do it when im upload project to hosting and put DEBUG = False?